# unban command discord.py rewrite

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I need an efficent discord.py command for unban users by their tag, not their name and discriminator. how i can do?
This is the code that I made and it works with `*unban name#1234`.

```py
@client.command()
@commands.has_any_role(702909770956406885, 545323952428417064, 545323570587369472)
async def unban(ctx, *, member):
    banned_user = await ctx.guild.bans()
    member_name, member_discriminator = member.split("#")
    for ban_entry in banned_user:
        user = ban_entry.user

        if (user.name, user.discriminator) == (member_name, member_discriminator):
            await ctx.guild.unban(user)
            embed = discord.Embed(title="Fatto!", description=f"Ho sbannato {user.mention}!", color=discord.Color.green())
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
            return
```

How can i make it work with tags? I know you can't directly tag a banned user but with his id you can do it. Thank you for answers!

Answer (score 2):

**Hope this helps**

```
from discord.ext.commands import has_permissions

@bot.command()
@has_permissions(ban_members=True)
async def unban(ctx, userId: discord.User.id):
  user = get(id=userId)
  await ctx.guild.unban(user)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [member](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member) object as a parameter in your unban function.

Ex:

```py
@client.command()
@commands.has_any_role(702909770956406885, 545323952428417064, 545323570587369472)
async def unban(ctx, *, member: discord.Member):
    await ctx.guild.unban(member)
```

Then in discord you could execute the command by mentioning the user.
Ex: `*unban @aleee`

Answer (score 0):

```py
@client.command(description="bans a user with specific reason (only admins)") #ban
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def ban (ctx, member:discord.User=None, reason =None):
 try:
    if (reason == None):
        await ctx.channel.send("You  have to specify a reason!")
        return
    if (member == ctx.message.author or member == None):
        await ctx.send("""You cannot ban yourself!""") 
    else:
        message = f"You have been banned from {ctx.guild.name} for {reason}"
        await member.send(message)
        await ctx.guild.ban(member, reason=reason)
        print(member)
        print(reason)
        await ctx.channel.send(f"{member} is banned!")
 except:
    await ctx.send(f"Error banning user {member} (cannot ban owner or bot)")
```

Comment: this is a routine to ban users by name and does not answer the question, which is "unban by tag"